# I have to write a c code in assembly but I am having problems seeing the output of the code by using CPUlator

Tags: assembly, mips

I wrote this code in c and now I am trying to pass to assembly. My biggest problem right now is by using this simulator https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=mipsr5b to see if my code worked. Does anyone that has used that before can help me please? Like how do I know if my code is working because I get compile succeed but I don't get any output, and I am still trying to understand what is going on with the registers.

C code - It' a simple function that returns an absolute value

```
int abs_calc(int x)
{
    if(x < 0)
    {
        return x * -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return x;
    }
}

int main (void) {

    int x = -10;
    int y = 0;
    y = abs_calc(x);
    printf("Absolute value of %i is %i",x,y);
};
```

Assembly code done using https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=mipsr5b

```
.set noreorder

.global _start
_start:
li $t0,-10 #storing -10 in register t0
xor $t1,$t1 #storing zero in register t1
li $t2, -1 #storing -1 in register t2
j PRINT #jumping to print
    
    
abs_calc:   
BGEZ $t0, store_result #if t0 > 0 jump to store result
j get_abs
store_result:
move $t1, $t0 #t0 = t1
j result_print
get_abs:
MUL $t1, $t2, $t0 #t1 = t2 * t0 (-1 * -10)
j result_print
    
PRINT:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, message1 #printing message
syscall
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t0 #printing integer
syscall

j abs_calc
result_print: 
li $v0, 4
la $a0, message2 #printing message result
syscall
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t1 #printing message answer
syscall
j DONE
    
DONE: 
li $v0, 10           # loading exit code
   syscall             # execute exit

.data
message1: .asciiz "Absolute value of "
message2: .asciiz "is "
```

Comment: You have selected a MIPS processor that has delay slots, but aren't writing code that has them.

Comment: You're not going to get any output with that processor selection, since it doesn't emulate any I/O devices.  You need the "SPIM" variant, rather than "generic".  To actually run your code, use the buttons along the top - "Continue" to try to run the whole program, one of the "Step" options to run it line-by-line.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you for trying to help. I am using the button in the top, more specific the one step into,  and when get in the line of output the line I get: Instruction fetched from a location outside of a code section (.text or .exceptions). So I think my code might be wrong when I try to output. Is it wrong?

Comment: You apparently are still using the "generic" processor variant, which doesn't implement `syscall`.  I was able to successfully run your code by selecting the "SPIM" variant, then clicking the "Apply and reload" button at the bottom of the Settings pane.